# Convert the string to the image in Quiz options SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio

I want to put a picture instead of a question ,to show the picture instead of the question, Quiz question is String how can put Image in addQuestion().

Please help me.

```
public QuizHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    dbase = db;
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
            + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    addQuestion();
    // db.close();

}

private void addQuestion() {
    Question q1 = new Question("5+2 =", "7", "8", "6", "7");
    this.addQuestion(q1);
    Question q2 = new Question("10+10 =", "18", "19", "20", "20");
    this.addQuestion(q2);
    Question q3 = new Question("3+4 =", "6", "7", "8", "7");
    this.addQuestion(q3);
    Question q4 = new Question("6+6 =", "12", "13", "14", "12");
    this.addQuestion(q4);
    Question q5 = new Question("5-3 =", "1", "3", "2", "2");
    this.addQuestion(q5);
    Question q6 = new Question("99-98 =", "1", "0", "10", "1");
    this.addQuestion(q6);
    Question q7 = new Question("0×0 =", "0", "9", "1", "0");
    this.addQuestion(q7);
    Question q8 = new Question("8+1 =", "8", "7", "9", "9");
    this.addQuestion(q8);
    Question q9 = new Question("3×2 =", "6", "7", "5", "6");
    this.addQuestion(q9);
    // END
}

}
```

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Comment: set image in Question like this "Question q1 = new Question(R.drawable.img, "6", "7", "5", "6");"

Comment: so you done ???

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to display an image containing the text of the question instead of a string there are many options. For example you can use the Swing library and create a JLabel containing the text of the question.

```
JLabel yourLabel = new JLabel(yourQuestion); 

//later you can change this question by this way:

yourLabel.setText(anotherQuestion);
```